# How to redefine Fortran comment character for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, fortran90

I am coding in fortran90 on Emacs (no-windows mode) with `fortran-mode`. I have only used Emacs for Python for which it works without problem but now that I have switched to fortran90 I have many little issues that I don't know how to configure.

The biggest problem I have is with the commenting region command. I usually use <kbd>M-;</kbd> to comment regions but I get something like this:

```
c$$$  if (x1.eq.0) then
```

I know about the command

<kbd>C-x r t</kbd>

which actually does the trick (I can insert a `!` at the beginning of each line) but I am so used to the <kbd>M-;</kbd> command and I wish I could keep using it. Also, with the latter command I can comment *and* un-comment the region.

So what I want to do is to replace the symbol for commenting in (and only in) `fortran-mode`. And such that it works every time I open/close Emacs with `fortran-mode`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't coded in Fortran for the last 30 years (!), and I'm not acquainted with Fortran mode in Emacs. But looking at library `fortran.el` I see that there are some user options for customizing comment behavior.  Take a look at them by using `M-x customize-group fortran-comment`.  The doc for each should be self-explanatory.  If not, more info is available in the Emacs manual -- see node `Fortran` and its subnodes, in particular, node `Fortran Comments`. It specifically talks about `M-;` in the context of Fortran mode, for instance.